# How to update order status to shipped instead of preparing

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

When i add tracking no to the order and click on **Submit Shipment** , Order status becomes **preparing** and *Preparing email is sent to customer* . Then again ,i **have to change the status to Shipped** .

What i want is to change order status to **Shipped** when **Submit Shipment** is clicked . Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this,you need to Override controller class `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController`

***saveAction()*** function at   after **$this->_saveShipment($shipment);**
You  need forcefully reset order status.

```
$Order=$shipment->getOrder();
$Order->setStatus('YOUR_STATUS_CODE');
$Order->save();
```

Comment: thanks @Amit , I will try this and let you know if it worked for me or not .